# Is there a specific name for this geometrical shape?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I’m looking for the name of this shape which is basically created by shaping symmetrical round edges of a 2D circle after forming it roundly from the center (I hope I’m explaining it correctly without having the correct technical terms)

[image: geometrical shape]

Comment: I don't think there is a specific mathematical name for such a surface. But, if you are looking for an equation $z=f(x,y)$ that can generate such a shape on a computer, it is possible to find one.

Comment: @JeanMarie aw! That’s cool. Thanks for the formula. I’m mainly looking for a way of shaping this out of clay in the most symmetric way possible.

Comment: Among the infinite number of such shapes (such "moulds", one could say), are you looking for a shape with a specific property ? The interest of having a graphical representation of a surface depending on a parameter say $a$ under the form $z=f_a(x,y)$ (I don't know if you are accustomed to this kind of notations) can help in order to find the "most satisfying" value of $a$ on an esthetical point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are interested by a simulation of this surface, here is a result obtained by the technique of "morphing" from a first level curve to a second level curve.

[image]